# Regarding missing connection string in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]

I am learning basics of MVC. And forgive me If I am not able to ask question properly because I am not aware of various technical terms. Anyways I am trying build one simple page where I will have two tables **courses** and **Instructors**. I am able to do most of the stuff and it seems to be working. Also I do have a solution given by my faculty of the same problem. When I am comparing my solution and faculty solution then in the web.config file of the actual solution given by my faculty I see something like

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcCRUDwithSQL-20140217025002.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcCRUDwithSQL-20140217025002;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="CourseContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=CourseContext-20140217145250; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|CourseContext-20140217145250.mdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Where as in my solution that I just have **one add name tag**. I don't know why the another tag did not get created automatically. Or do I need to add that tag manually.

```
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication9-20150313042831.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication9-20150313042831;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Have I done something wrong that the connection string related to **CourseContext** did not get generated automatically. Or we need to add for **CourseContext** manually? Please help me. Since most of the files and its content are generated automatically I must have done something wrong that connection string pertaining to CourseContext did not get generated.

Comment: VS sometimes will make you a default connection automaticaly

Comment: You will have to add it in manually or you can use the server explorer in vs to generate one. Please don't use unnecessary tags i.e `asp-classic` because this has nothing to do with it

Comment: Can you please guide me how to generate it automatically. Because the syntax has some file name with random numbers and all. So I am assuming simply copy pasting faculty's line of code won't work.

Comment: Please, refer to [Dynamic Connection String](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/755380/Dynamic-Connection-String) article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need one connection for each table, you only need one connection for each database. A database can contain many tables (the project I'm working on right now has 9 tables, and that is a really small project).

The Visual Studio template starts out with a default connection string, but no database. It looks like it's that connection string that is still left in the solution.

Comment: Suppose I want to replicate the way my professor did. I also want to have the connection string for CourseContext as in my professor solution. If I see the syntax closely its pretty complicated with some content as "Initial Catalog=CourseContext-20140217145250" .. So it must be generated automatically. How can I achieve it.

Comment: Do you have a second database to connect? The `DefaultConnection` connection is for a database file named `aspnet-MvcCRUDwithSQL-20140217025002.mdf`. If you have a second database you can just copy the connection string and put your database name in the file name and initial catalog settings. If you don't have a second database, you don't need a second connection string.

Comment: I just have one database. So I think as per you I don't need the other connection string. :)

Comment: So if I have one database this default connection take care of everything for me. is it?

Comment: I am sorry if I am not making much of a sense. I am learning these stuffs for the first time.

Comment: @tanz: The default connection works fine if the connection type (MDF file) is what you use, and the file name is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Use the steps below to generate the connection string via visual studio server explorer

1. Click on server explorer
2. Connect to database
3. Choose server name from dropdown
4. Choose your authentication type
5. Select your database from dropdown
6. Test connection
7. Copy the connection string from the properties and paste in your `web.config`

[image]

Also take a note of @Guffa answer, he's got a very good point

Comment: For those reading this : server explorer is under the View Menu in VS 2017 :)